# WCF javascript proxy not found when endpoint address is not blank

Tags: .net, wcf, javascript-debugger

I am trying to setup a WCF service with multiple endpoints with one of the endpoints using the enableWebScript endpoint behavior so that a Javascript proxy will be created on the client (jsdebug/js).

When adding the Service Reference to my AJAX ScriptManager, the jsdebug file is not found unless the address of the endpoint is blank. The ScriptManager proxy seems to always generate a path of "MyService.svc/jsdebug" to look for the file even though my service has an address of "ajax". The proxy should generate the path as "MyService.svc/ajax/jsdebug".

Is there a setting to get the Proxy generated with the right path? My service is at the root of my website.

works:

```
<endpoint address="" 
  behaviorConfiguration="ajaxBehavior" 
  binding="webHttpBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
  contract="MyTest.Web.ICustomerService" />
```

want this (doesn't work):

```
<endpoint address="ajax" 
  behaviorConfiguration="ajaxBehavior" 
  binding="webHttpBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
  contract="MyTest.Web.ICustomerService" />
```

Comment: what is your base address? are you connecting into the right path like www.mydomain.com/service.svc/ajax ?

Comment: What settings did you use for your script manager..?

Answer (score 2):

`<enableWebScript />` also known as AJAX-enabled endpoints essentially hard-codes everything to do with address so you can generate the client-side code.

The way it's hard-coded is that everything is directly relative to the .svc file.

See [How to: Use Configuration to Add an ASP.NET AJAX Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628467.aspx)

> The endpoint is configured at an empty
>   address relative to the .svc file, so
>   the service is now available and can
>   be invoked by sending requests to
>   `service.svc/<operation>` - for example,
>   `service.svc/Add` for the `Add` operation.

For this reason, you can't mix `<enableWebScript />` with `UriTemplate`, which takes away half the fun out of WCF in my opinion. See [enableWebScript, UriTemplate, and HTTP methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/justinjsmith/archive/2008/02/15/enablewebscript-uritemplate-and-http-methods.aspx).

Personally, I like to configure my URI and serve both POX and JSON, as well as SOAP. See [WCF RESTful POX, JSON and SOAP Coexist](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the ScriptManager, put MyService.svc/ajax instead of MyService.svc